# JavaScript streaming player with iPhone support

Tags: javascript, iphone, streaming, mp4

I'm searching for a web video player. It needs to be free and for commercial use. It shouldn't not be Flash-based because iOS doesn't support it. It should also support streaming and MPEG-4, AVI, etc.

Comment: I saw that this player used flowplayer for mp4 files...but flowplayer is not free for commercial use. Any other program solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A pure Javascript library GUI controls (play, plause, ..) for data streams.
you can find here https://github.com/romsson/StreamPlayer

For more detail read here https://github.com/romsson/StreamPlayer/wiki